# Forward slashes in part numbers are breaking mod_rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a simple mod_rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?partNumber=$1&partName=$2 [L]
```

It works great for 99.99% of products but there are 3 or 4 products which have a forward slash in their part number (eg PART001/1)

which rewrites to something like:

```
/product/PART001/1/part-name-here-for-nice-seo
```

Obviously this doesn't work as it's looking in an extra directory. I need the part number passed correctly as it's used to look up the index in the database and fetch all the product's information.

Is there any way round this?

Comment: What is part number in `/product/PART001/1/part-name-here-for-nice-seo` and why are you getting these malformed URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to change the `([^/.]+)` grouping in your regex to also match slashes. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?partNumber=$1&partName=$2 [L]
```